# String with Object to Object

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var arr = "[{'one' : '1'}, {'two' : '2'}]";
```

How can I pass this string to an object?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work:

```
arr.split(',');
```

Comment: What do you mean by passing the string to object ?

Comment: If this string is coming from a data source, (e.g you're not typing it, and you have no control over it) you should tell them that it is invalid JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must first transform single quotes to double quotes then use JSON.parse

`JSON.parse(arr.replace(/'/g,'"'))`